# Table Lock Fails

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting a table to lock in MySQL. I've tried testing for concurrent requests by running two scripts at the same time on different browsers.

Script 1:

```
mysql_query("lock tables id_numbers write");

$sql = "select number from id_numbers";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $id = $record['number'];
}

sleep(30);

$id++;

$sql = "update id_numbers set number = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_query("unlock tables");
```

Script 2:

```
$sql = "select number from id_numbers";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $id = $record['number'];
}

echo $id;
```

I start Script 1 first, then start Script 2.  Theoretically, Script 2 should wait 30+ seconds until Script 1 unlocks the table, and then output the updated ID.  But it immediately outputs the original ID, so the lock is obviously not taking effect.  What could be going wrong?

BTW, I know I shouldn't still be using mysql_*, but I'm stuck with it for now.

EDIT: I've discovered that the lock does happen on the live site, but not on my dev site. They are both on shared hosts, so I'm assuming there's some setting that's different between the two. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: your locking writing, not reading.

Comment: @Dagon Yes, I want to both read and write. According to the MySQL manual, "WRITE lock: The session that holds the lock can read and write the table. Only the session that holds the lock can access the table. No other session can access it until the lock is released. Lock requests for the table by other sessions block while the WRITE lock is held." That's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you have here, I get exactly the behavior you expect: script 2 will block until script 1 issues the `unlock tables`.

Your problem must lie elsewhere. Things to check:

1. Does the table actually exist on the database? (Check your `mysql_query()` return values and use `mysql_error()` if you get any `FALSE` returns.)
2. Are both scripts connecting to the *same* database?
3. Are you sure the table is not a temporary (thus connection-local) table?
4. Could script 1's mysql connection (or the script itself) be timing out during the `sleep(30)`, thus releasing the lock earlier than you expect?

Comment: Oops! I made a mistake when writing the question. The actual script does lock id_numbers.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I didn't realize your answer had changed. Yes to 1, 2 & 3. #4: Changing the sleep length doesn't make any difference. See the edit to my original question.

Comment: Does the DB user have permission to lock tables?